# D3-Force-Quicker stabilization of nodes & transition of elements in projectiles

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, force-layout

I have implemented the following version of the force diagram to show inter-cluster movement of nodes.

https://jsfiddle.net/Edwig_Noronha/67ey5rz0/

The nodes are grouped into four clusters. After the first initialization of the force diagram ends I call a function to transition the nodes from source to destination clusters.

```
function moveNodes() {        
        Object.keys(inputdata).forEach(function(key, index) {
            svg.selectAll("circle.viewernodes" + index)
                .each(function(d) {
                    d.type = d.destination;
                });
        });
        viewersTransitioned = true;
        force.start();
    }
```

However, The stabilization of the first initialization of the force diagram takes about 35 seconds. Hence the transition happens after that much time.

Q1) is it possible to achieve a quicker stabilization of the force diagram with collision detection?

The transition of the nodes from source to destination clusters happens along a linear path.

Q2) Is it possible to make the nodes move along projectile paths?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve quicker stabilization you can do one of two things in my experience.

1. **Initialize the nodes X and Y values to be near to their end/goal state**

Such as nodes[i].x = 500 etc, then calling the simulation start.

This would somewhat defeat the purpose of what you're trying to show in your example, unless you don't want the nodes to be shown moving to the groups and just be in them to begin with...

2. **Stronger force**

Have the force moving/pulling the nodes be stronger. This would require an essentially fundamental change to your approach to this example. Instead of just transitioning their positions, create custom forces within your force-layout that affect the appropriate nodes only based on their attributes. Place these forces in the center of your 'sorting circles' and they would attract the nodes appropriately.

See here for what something like this would look like: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021841

Comment: I have made the changes to implement both of these two things in the jsfiddle code. I have initialized the nodes closer to their cluster centers (lines 140,141) and I have also increased the force with which they are pulled towards their clusters (lines 173,182,183). This may have reduced the stabilization time a little. @A Zibuda thank you. I am looking for still more optimizations in stabilization.